# minimal cost sum

Tags: c++, algorithm

i want to to calculate minimum sum  in given  two dimensional array

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits.h>
using namespace std;
#define R 3
#define C 3
int Min(int x,int y,int z){
   if(x<y){
        return (x<z)?x:z;
   }
   else
       return (y<z)?y:z;
   }
int mincost(int cost[R][C],int m,int n){

    int i,j;
    int t[R][C];
    t[0][0]=cost[0][0];
    for(i=1;i<=m;i++)
        t[i][0]=t[i-1][0]+cost[i][0];
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
t[0][j]=t[0][j-1]+cost[0][j];
    for(i=1;i<=m;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
            t[i][j]=Min(t[i-1][j-1],t[i-1][j],t[i][j-1]+cost[i][j]);
        }
    }
      return t[m][n];

}

int main(){

    int cost[R][C]={{1,2,3},
                    {4,8,2},
                    {1,5,3}};
    cout<<mincost(cost,2,2)<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

from starting point (0,0) to  some point (m,n)   for this array   it equals 8,but output shows me 1,why?what is wrong with this  code?
algorithm in words

> Given a cost matrix cost[][] and a position (m, n) in cost[][], write a function that returns cost of minimum cost path to reach (m, n) from (0, 0). Each cell of the matrix represents a cost to traverse through that cell. Total cost of a path to reach (m, n) is sum of all the costs on that path (including both source and destination). You can only traverse down, right and diagonally lower cells from a given cell, i.e., from a given cell (i, j), cells (i+1, j), (i, j+1) and (i+1, j+1) can be traversed. You may assume that all costs are positive integers.

Comment: Can you describe your algorithm in words? That would be appropriate for a comment block in your code.

Comment: I can't think of any way to interpret that where the result is 8, except for finding the maximum element :(

Comment: The description you added was not a description of your *algorithm*, but rather a description of the *problem statement*.

Comment: yes but ,here is hint for algorithm,so  what is problem about my  problem definitions? it is dynamic implementation of  code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that this is a dynamic programming solution.

you have a typo here:

```
t[i][j]=Min(t[i-1][j-1],t[i-1][j],t[i][j-1]+cost[i][j]);
```

it should be:

```
t[i][j]=Min(t[i-1][j-1],t[i-1][j],t[i][j-1]) + cost[i][j];
```

basically it worked like `t[i][j] = t[i-1][j-1]`.

Note: A good way to debug these problems is to print the intermediate matrix (here: `t`).

Answer (score 1):

Given that t[0][0] = cost[0][0] = 1
then

```
for(i=1;i<=m;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
            t[i][j]=Min(t[i-1][j-1],t[i-1][j],t[i][j-1]+cost[i][j]);
        }
```

for i=1, j=1

```
t[1][1] = Min(t[0][0], t[0][1], t[1][0]+cost[1][1]) = Min(1, ...) = 1
```

for i=2 j=2

```
t[2][2] = Min(t[1][1], t[1][2], t[2][1]+cost[2][2]) = Min(1, ...) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Min(t[i-1][j-1],t[i-1][j],t[i][j-1]+cost[i][j])
```

should probably be

```
Min(t[i-1][j-1],t[i-1][j],t[i][j-1]) +cost[i][j]
```

Just guessing, it's hard to read your intent, but looks like a pathfinding algorithm.  Your code wasn't adding the cost properly to diagonal or horizontal movement, and since the cost of the beginning was one, that was also your result.  This should return a cost of eleven for your sample.